# Rails Postgre issue: malformed array literal, Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I created a new migration for my Rails app on Heroku. It adds some Array columns like this:

```
t.string :timezone, array: true, default: [].to_yaml
t.string :locale, array: true, default: [].to_yaml
```

I get the following error when I try to migrate:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: 
>   malformed array literal: "--- [] " DETAIL:  Array value must start
>   with "{" or dimension information. : CREATE TABLE "filters" ("id"
>   serial primary key, "letter_id" integer, "gender" character varying,
>   "timezone" character varying[] DEFAULT '--- [] ', "locale" character
>   varying[] DEFAULT '--- []

Here is my model:

```
class Filter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :letter
  serialize :timezone
  serialize :locale
  serialize :segment
  validates_uniqueness_of :letter_id
end
```

Some people on Stackoverflow say removing serialize will do the trick but I need to store an array, not a string.

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
t.text :your_table, :timezone, default: []
t.text :your_table, :locale, default: []
```

Not sure why you would ever call `to_yaml` for a default value. Also, you should use a column type of `text` since string will likely limit you to 255 characters by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did the following and it solved my issue:

```
t.string :timezone, :string
t.string :locale, :string
```

And kept my model with serialize.